# Getting condiitonal probability of n-gram using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

The N-gram model provides the probability of next word P(W) by seeing the history. (as per window size). How can I implement this in python using nltk?

Is there any pre-built package for the same?

I referred to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462709/nltk-language-model-ngram-calculate-the-prob-of-a-word-from-context). However I am not able to import `Ngram model`. It gives me error as,

> NameError: name 'NgramModel' is not defined

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit - It seems that the NgramModel has been removed due to some bugs. [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443084/is-there-an-alternate-for-the-now-removed-module-nltk-model-ngrammodel). So which alternate model can be used?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nltk language model (ngram) calculate the prob of a word from context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462709/nltk-language-model-ngram-calculate-the-prob-of-a-word-from-context)

Comment: What was your import statement?

Comment: I tried `from nltk.corpus import NgramModel` and `from nltk import NgramModel`

Comment: I also tried `from nltk.model import NgramModel` but it says `No module named model`

Comment: Aha, it seems that the module has been removed pending some issues. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/XdVKlhJ46nM