# Python - tool for word learn

Tags: python, cpu-word, language-model

Can I do something like this in python?
I have 3 sentences:

```
I like cats.
I like cats
I like cats
```

And it is possible when I give *I like*, the script returns *cats*?

Can somebody give me advice/tool or some example?

Comment: Use a Python dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

There are an unlimited number of ways to do that. You could make a script that just does this:

```
print("cats")
```

But, I don't think that's what you want. You're looking for a [Language Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model). Again, there are many ways of doing this, from the fairly simple Bayesian model to a more advanced neural network language model. If you want to build your own, I would recommend checking out [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org)'s [tutorial on language models](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/). Otherwise, you could use something that's a bit more off the shelf, such as [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org)'s [language model](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.model.html) (see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462709/nltk-language-model-ngram-calculate-the-prob-of-a-word-from-context)).